# cannot import TensorFlow even after re-installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, import

I tried to import TensorFlow in Jupyter notebook and VScode but always ended up with 'Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell. Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. Click here for more info. View Jupyter log for further details.'

I tried to uninstall TensorFlow and install back using 'pip install tensorflow' and 'python3 -m install tensorflow'. Although I got TensorFlow back in both ways, neither works and I still have the same error.

Here is the log:

```
15:55:19.800 [error] Error in waiting for cell to complete [Error: Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
    at t.KernelShellFutureHandler.dispose (~/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.4.1011241018-darwin-arm64/out/extension.node.js:2:32419)
    at ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.4.1011241018-darwin-arm64/out/extension.node.js:2:51471
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at v._clearKernelState (~/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.4.1011241018-darwin-arm64/out/extension.node.js:2:51456)
    at v.dispose (~/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.4.1011241018-darwin-arm64/out/extension.node.js:2:44938)
    at ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.4.1011241018-darwin-arm64/out/extension.node.js:24:105531
    at te (~/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.4.1011241018-darwin-arm64/out/extension.node.js:2:1587099)
    at Zg.dispose (~/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.4.1011241018-darwin-arm64/out/extension.node.js:24:105507)
    at nv.dispose (~/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.4.1011241018-darwin-arm64/out/extension.node.js:24:112790)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)]
15:55:19.801 [warn] Cell completed with errors {
  message: 'Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done'
}
15:55:19.801 [warn] Cancel all remaining cells due to cancellation or failure in execution
```

Also when I use `pip show tensorflow` I have

> Name: tensorflow
> Version: 2.12.0
> Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
> Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
> Author: Google Inc.
> Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
> License: Apache 2.0
> Location: /Users/hanyusu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages
> Requires: absl-py, astunparse, flatbuffers, gast, google-pasta, grpcio, h5py, jax, keras, libclang, numpy, opt-einsum, packaging, protobuf, setuptools, six, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, termcolor, typing-extensions, wrapt
>
> Required-by:
> Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

BTW TensorFlow still works on Colab so I guess some dependency problem? But don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Hi @Hanyu Su, Please try installing the tensorflow using the TF Official [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#macos) and then install the [vs code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_create-or-open-a-jupyter-notebook) using jupyter notebook and set the python interpreter for the same. Let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the shell:

```bash
#  Requires the latest pip
pip install --upgrade pip

#  in a virtual environment or using Python 2
pip install tensorflow

#  for python 3 (could also be pip3.10 depending on your version)
pip3 install tensorflow

#  if you get permissions error
sudo pip3 install tensorflow
pip install tensorflow --user

# if you don't have pip in your PATH environment variable
python -m pip install tensorflow

#  for python 3 (could also be pip3.10 depending on your version)
python3 -m pip install tensorflow

#  using py alias (Windows)
py -m pip install tensorflow

# for Anaconda
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow

#  for Jupyter Notebook
!pip install tensorflow
```

`main.py`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
dataset1=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(https://learn.acloud.guru/dashboard([4, 10]))
print(dataset1.element_spec)
```

See also [this blog post](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-no-module-named-tensorflow).